# Replacing Windows 7 with ubuntu on a Lenovo T530

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, thinkpad

I am purchasing a Lenovo T530.I want to replace windows with Ubuntu 13.04.I contacted Lenovo customer support and asked if they offered one with out an operating system.I was told no and there was no way of removing windows.Is this true? IS there a way? Or am I forced to dual boot until my T530 is out of warranty?I know there are great makers out there that build machines to run Ubuntu.But.I have thinkpads dating back to 1999 and all run Ubuntu flawlessly.I want to keep with tradition.I have been a loyal Ubuntuer since Lucid.And have never turned back. I simply detest windows,so any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you! And thank you for The GREAT O.S.

Vince.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some jurisdictions will enable you to get a refund for the Window you are not using.

Aside from this, some manufacturers can be a bit of a problem in terms of support. Their support telephone operator scripts, etc, depend on Windows to work. Some will deny you support on the grounds that you installed an OS other than that supplied (although I'd be surprised if Lenovo was one of these).

That said, the T530 is certified "Enabled for Ubuntu" 
http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201205-11132/

Intel graphics controllers work well in Linux, as their drivers are both written by the manufacturer, and open-source as well.

Comment: Thank You very much for the quick response and great advice.I am elated to know that I can use Ubuntu on my new Lappy.I will use  suggestion.Thanks again!

Comment: The link is down and there is no T530 in the certification list...

Answer (score 0):

I got a lenovo laptop as well. What you are going to have to do is keep a copy of the windows CD Key and a copy of the D:\ or E:\ drive you might have which contains copies of all the drivers you have. Also note the type of windows installation, pro, home regular, home premium, etc.

If you ever need to send it back since you did a sector by sector copy of it or kept the partition they can't say u deleted anything. Just make sure to install windows before you send it in, this would mean grabbing an iso from a torrent site; but you wouldn't need to apply a crack b/c the cd key should check out.

Also in regards to their warrenty you should know that lenovo does not to backups meaning they wipe your drive if anything goes wrong. What they do is refurbish it and just send you a new model.

Comment: Thank You very much for the quick response and great advice.I am elated to know that I can use Ubuntu on my new Lappy.I will use your suggestion.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You **can** remove *Windows* and install *Ubuntu* instead of it, but it's highly probably that **you'll lose your warrany** (you can ask customer support about that to make sure).

Also, please note that HDD has limitation of 4 primary partitions which could be used by pre-installed software like backup partitions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ubuntu from the start and I have been using thinkpads since 1998.  Lenovo will give you hardware support even if you wipe your windows.  There is a tonne of support for software issues on the web.  The hardware is well supported on ubuntu with the only issue that I have ever had being hibernate is a hit or miss.  I always wipe windows and do not keep a copy of the partions and lenovo support has never given me a hard time.  When I have to send it in for repair I normally pull the harddrive out but not always.  My thinking is, if the keyboard or monitor etc is broken, they do not need my hard drive to fix it.  This has never been an issue.  If you send it in for repair there is a form that you complete and you con give them permission or deny them permission on restore your hard drive.  My T61 video card just bit the dust and I will probably purchase a T530 today and I am not worried about being able to install ubuntu or get support from lenovo.